# Django python How to insert a json containing several objects in postgresql

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, object

I would like to insert a json containing several publications in my database. I want to create a field for each publication. For the moment I managed to insert a json containing a single publication, however when I try with two, it makes me a mistake:

***Script python :***

```
fichier = open("result2.json","r")
filedata = json.load(fichier)
#for '{' in filedata:
   #print "ici un {"
prod = Production()
prod.cle = filedata.get("UT")
prod.titre = filedata.get("TITRE")
prod.publis = filedata
prod.maj = timezone.now()
prod.save()
fichier.close()
```

***result2.json***

```
{
   "UT": "WOS:123456",
   "TI": "firstpubli",
   "DT": "journal",
   "PY": "2016",
   "TITRE" :"firstpubli2016",
   "AU": "me, you"
 }
```

***What does it do***
[enter image description here][1]

***Now if I put 2 publications in result2.json:***

```
 {
   "UT": "WOS:123456",
   "TI": "firstpubli",
   "DT": "journal",
   "PY": "2016",
   "TITRE" :"firstpubli2016",
   "AU": "me, you"
 }   
 {
   "UT": "WOS:78910",
   "TI": "secondpubli",
   "DT": "journal",
   "PY": "2016",
   "TITRE" :"secondpubli2016",
   "AU": "me, you"
 }
```

***When I run the python script to insert the data, I have this error***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 45, in <module>
    filedata = json.load(fichier)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 12 column 2 - line 21 column 1 (char 143 - 282)
```

And nothing is inserted in the database
My goal is to get like on this image, 2 productions, when I have 2 productions in my json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wc6Y.png)

Comment: Shouldn't you put comma between entries in JSON? I mean, `} , {` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is not a json string. If you want more than one object to insert you should user list.
your file should be as follows :
`[{
   "UT": "WOS:123456",
   "TI": "firstpubli",
   "DT": "journal",
   "PY": "2016",
   "TITRE" :"firstpubli2016",
   "AU": "me, you"
 },
 {
   "UT": "WOS:78910",
   "TI": "secondpubli",
   "DT": "journal",
   "PY": "2016",
   "TITRE" :"secondpubli2016",
   "AU": "me, you"
 }]`

Also you should change your code like this : 

    `filedata = json.load(fichier)
    for f in filedata:
        //object insertion here`